# php file url rewrite without using mod rewrite

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

Lets say i have a website which have a php file like

```
mysite.com/blogs.php
```

i want the url to look like

```
mysite.com/blog
```

I know that we can use mod `rewrite` but is there any options available better than that??

I came up with something like creating folder named `blog` in the root directory, and then put a `index.php` file in that folder and we can call this file by the following url

```
mysite.com/blog
```

So here are my questions:

1. What is the best way to rewrite or creating a fancy url?
2. What is the security risk involved?
3. Is there any performance issue to note?

Comment: Use `../` to point your link to a folder in the directory above the current directory.  

Or - if you're using the same footer in every page - use absolute URLs.

For example:  `../mysite/blog`.

Comment: @james thats not the point i want a root url like "www.mysite.com/user.php"

Answer (score 0):

remove the `.`
use absolute path instead

`<a href="/user.php">...</a>`